# Как вывести на сайте опцию - музыка из вконтакте

Tags: php, javascript

Кто подскажет как реализовать такой вывод музыки: http://www.ktokogda.com/send/app/#/cards/section/191/page/1/item/4670

Перечитан мануал вконтатке, найдено решение как отобразить музыку из аккаунта пользователя, а вот как вывести всю базу аудио не могу найти!!!

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$access_token = '123'; // access_token пользователя, полученный с помощью приложения

$api_get = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?access_token='.$access_token), true);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($api_get); // необходимо распарсить полученные результаты из массива $api_get в нужный вид
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

О том, как авторизовать пользователя и получить его **access_token**, написано [**здесь**](http://vk.com/dev/auth_sites).